# What does Tornado do with active requests when it is stopped?

Tags: python, tornado, supervisord

Question pretty much says it all. If I am running Tornado on a server with Supervisor, what happens to active requests when I deploy code and need to restart the Tornado server? Are they dropped mid-request? Are they allowed to finish?

Comment: Not really a supervisord problem; supervisord would restart the daemon the same way anything else would, with a SIGTERM.

Answer (score 2):

Supervisord send a signal like HUP or TERM to tornado process, the most important point is how tornado deal with it.

Unfortunately, tornado will simple exit when it get signal like HUP, TERM,  INT.

Tornado has a sub module named autoreload, it make the application could detect the code files' changes and reload the application, but it only works the debug mode for one process, and not in WSGI applications. It's development tool.

But, we can define a function within run tornado.autoreload._reload function by manual, and register it for HUP sigal. [tornado.autoreload.add_reload_hook](http://www.tornadoweb.org/documentation/autoreload.html#tornado.autoreload.add_reload_hook) can add functions should be called when reload.

Because the tornado doesn't manage the processes well on fork mode, so it's suggested running many independent processes for different ports. On this mode, the _reload will works like set debug flag.

After all, test and benchmark it for make sure it works well in your application.